# Node.js - Exporting and referring to constants

Tags: node.js

I am new into Node.js, and I am trying to create a server for a real time project of mine. I am a bit puzzled thought, as I have defined some constants in a module, that, although, I export they are not available in any other module referring at it. i.e. 
the constants containing module is like:

```
--- constants.js
///// ---- CONSTANTS ---- /////
exports.MessageType =  {
    START_GAME: "001",
    END_GAME: "002",
    LIVE_STAT: "003",
    PAUSE_GAME: "004"
};
```

while the main module has:

```
var MessageType= require('constants').MessageType

...

switch (msgType) {
   case MessageType.START_GAME: ...
}
```

-- Running the above results in an errro:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'START_GAME' of undefined
```

---

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

`require('constants')` returns the Node.js built-in `constants` module.

To include a file in your directory, you need to pass a relative path:

```
require('./constants')
```

Comment: I have tried either. All fail. Did you try it your self and works?

Comment: @wirewolf: This will work, assuming the file exists at that path. What error do you get?

Comment: I get the very same error! The file does exist, WebStorm even allows me autocompletion!

Comment: @wirewolf: Try `require.resolve('./constants')` from the Node REPL in that directory & look at the result.